# API Gateway not retrieving request body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a `POST` endpoint in API gateway with request body in `application/json` type. Now, in input body mapping template, I want to check if the input is there and if the required fields are present or not. I tried getting input body using `$input.body` and also tried `$input.json('$')` and  `$input.path('$')`. Nothing works, input body is always empty, although the `$input.body == ""` check always returns false. But in the test logs i can see that the body is passed through. I'm using `Mock` as integration type. What can be an issue?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm having the same issue with the response body with API gateway endpoint when I try exactly this.